# $F:Mat_{m_xn}(K)\rightarrow Hom(K^n,K^m)$ , Prove F is bijective.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $A_{m_xn}(K)$ with $K$ a Field
Let $T:K^n\rightarrow K^m$.

Let $F:Mat_{m_xn}(K)\rightarrow Hom(K^n,K^m)$.

Show that F is bijective.

I need prove F is injective and surjective. I don't know how start this exercise, Can someone help me with a Hint? I'm very grateful!

Comment: I believe you mean *bijective*?

Comment: What's $F$?....

Comment: @Randall A linear Transformation.

Comment: @Bvss12 you haven't given an explicit description for what $F$ actually does. Are you asking if there exists a bijective morphism between this set of matrices and homomorphisms between the two vector spaces of fixed finite dimensions?

Comment: Yes @user1876508, is that.

Comment: You should probably change your question then.